# Python - Firebase DB reference error

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update certain node in my Firebase DB, so this is what I'm doing:

```
from firebase_admin import db

def update_data_in_firebase(gid, account_id, location_id, data_to_update):
    firebase_url = 'saved_locations/{}/accounts/{}/locations/{}'.format(gid, account_id, location_id)
    ref = db.reference(path=firebase_url)
    ref.update(data_to_update)
```

So, the code above is what I'm trying to do to update the data in the Firebase node, but I'm getting this error:

`Invalid databaseURL option: "None". databaseURL must be a non-empty URL string.`

Of course, I checked out the firebase URL and it matches, so the problem is not the URL, or, I'm missing something with the path, I mean, should I use *absolute* insted of *relative* path.

Comment: Do you have databaseURL set in your config when instantiating the firebase app?

Comment: In fact, it was that @OluwafemiSule. When setting up the Firebase App, the **databaseURL** was not defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, the **databaseURL** was not defined.

Answer:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('your_config.json')
firebase_admin = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://your-firebase-db'})
```

In the main docs of Firebase, I couldn't find the error on my *app* initialization:
[Firebase Admin Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
But in the [Realtime Database - Admin (Get Started)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), there is a snippet where they initialize the *Firebase App* defining the **databaseURL**